# I am trying to read a pdf file and display it in python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

The program doesn't read the text, it just prints a blank line . And the pdf is just one page

```
# importing required modules 
import PyPDF2 
  
# creating a pdf file object 
pdfFileObj = open("C:\\Users\\Uthkarsh Gaikwad\\Desktop\\SIMPLE DBMS\\presciption\\Pdf1.pdf", 'rb') 

# creating a pdf reader object 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(pdfReader.numPages) 

# creating a page object 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 

# extracting text from page 
print(pageObj.extractText()) 

# closing the pdf file object 
pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: maybe PDF has text as images - and then you can't get it. And then it needs OCR program to recognize text on image. ie. [tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/) developed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Some other solutions:

```
from tika import parser 

raw = parser.from_file("C:\\Users\\Uthkarsh Gaikwad\\Desktop\\SIMPLE DBMS\\presciption\\Pdf1.pdf")

print(raw['content'])
```

Or:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("C:\\Users\\Uthkarsh Gaikwad\\Desktop\\SIMPLE DBMS\\presciption\\Pdf1.pdf")
```